# Keyboard lifting bottom button

Tags: android, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I need to have a button at the bottom of the screen, but as soon as I tap on a textfield, keyboard shows up and lifts the button with it. I've tried using a button, another stacklayout, a scrollview wrapping it all... nothing's working and I feel I'm not understanding layouts correctly.

It's the gray button -> [I want the gray button there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLTpz.png)

But it always comes up with the keyboard, [see?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNQ5g.png)

It's my understanding that this should be a scrollview so it remains at it's bottom position, but if I add a ScrollView to the gridLayout so it scrolls, it doesn't work.

Here's the code. Thank you in advance.

```
<ActionBar android:title="Entrega {{id}}/{{detalleRuta.delegacion}}/{{detalleRuta.tipoAlbaran}}">
    <ActionItem>
        <Label *ngIf="!entrega.foto" cssClass="mdi icon-cam" [text]="'mdi-add-a-photo' | fonticon" ios.position="right" (tap)="getFoto()"></Label>
        <Label *ngIf="entrega.foto" cssClass="mdi icon-cam" [text]="'mdi-photo' | fonticon" ios.position="right" (tap)="showFoto()"></Label>
    </ActionItem>   
    <ActionItem>
        <Label class="mdi icon-map" [text]="'mdi-event-busy' | fonticon" ios.position="right" (tap)="cancelarEntrega()"></Label>
    </ActionItem>
</ActionBar>
<GridLayout rows="auto,*, 50" loaded="pageLoaded">
    <ListView row="0" [items]="detalle">
        <template let-item="item">
            <StackLayout orientation="vertical" class="info-entrega">
                <Label *ngIf="item.fechaActual" [text]="'Fecha ' + item.fechaActual"></Label>
                <Label *ngIf="item.horaActual"  [text]="'Hora ' + item.horaActual"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </template>
    </ListView>
    <TabView row="1" selectedIndex="0" selectedColor="#00B4E6" *ngIf="!noEntregado">
        <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Cliente'}">
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout class="formulario">
                <TextField [(ngModel)]="entrega.nombreCliente" hint="Nombre Cliente" keyboardType="text" autocorrect="false" autocapitalizationType="none"></TextField>
                <TextField [(ngModel)]="entrega.DNICliente" hint="DNI Cliente" keyboardType="text" autocorrect="false" autocapitalizationType="none"></TextField>
                <TextField [(ngModel)]="entrega.emailCliente" hint="Email Cliente" keyboardType="email" autocorrect="false" autocapitalizationType="none"></TextField>
                <Button style="width:100%" class="btn {{ entrega.firmaCliente ? 'conFirma' : 'sinFirma' }}" text="Firma Cliente" (tap)="firmaCliente(false)"></Button>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Empleado'}">
        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout class="form-config">
                <TextField class="input-config" [(ngModel)]="entrega.nombreEmpleado" hint="Nombre Empleado" keyboardType="text" autocorrect="false" autocapitalizationType="none"></TextField>
                <TextField class="input-config" [(ngModel)]="entrega.DNIEmpleado" hint="Dni Empleado" keyboardType="text" autocorrect="false" autocapitalizationType="none"></TextField>
                <Button style="width:100%" cssClass="btn {{ entrega.firmaEmpleado ? 'conFirma' : 'sinFirma' }}" text="Firma Empleado" (tap)="firmaEmpleado(false)"></Button>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Importes'}">
        <ScrollView *ngIf="detalleRuta.importePdte != 0">
            <StackLayout class="form-config">
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label *ngIf="entrega.impMetalico" class="impMetalico" [text]="'Metálico ' + impMetalicoCurrency"></Label>
                    <TextField id="impMetalico" keyboardType="number" [(ngModel)]="entrega.impMetalico" hint="Importe en Metálico" (textChange)="cambioMetalico($event)"></TextField>
                </StackLayout>

                <StackLayout>
                    <Label *ngIf="entrega.impTarjeta" class="impTarjeta" [text]="'Tarjeta ' + impTarjetaCurrency"></Label>
                    <TextField id="impTarjeta" keyboardType="number" [(ngModel)]="entrega.impTarjeta" hint="Importe en Tarjeta" (textChange)="cambioTarjeta($event)"></TextField>
                </StackLayout>

                 <StackLayout>
                    <Label *ngIf="entrega.impVale" class="impVale" [text]="'Vale ' + impValeCurrency"></Label>
                    <TextField id="impVale" keyboardType="number" [(ngModel)]="entrega.impVale" hint="Importe en Vale" (textChange)="cambioVale($event)"></TextField>
                </StackLayout>

                <StackLayout>
                    <Label *ngIf="entrega.impOtros" class="impOtros" [text]="'Otros ' + impOtrosCurrency"></Label>
                    <TextField id="impOtros" keyboardType="number" [(ngModel)]="entrega.impOtros" hint="Importe en Otros" (textChange)="cambioOtros($event)"></TextField>
                </StackLayout>

                <StackLayout>
                    <Label *ngIf="entrega.total" class="total" [text]="'Total ' + totalCurrency"></Label>
                </StackLayout>

                <StackLayout class="sumTotal">
                    <Label *ngIf="sumTotal" class="total" [text]="'Total ' + sumTotal | myCurrency"></Label>
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
        <StackLayout *ngIf="detalleRuta.importePdte == 0">
            <Label class="sinImporte" text="El importe Pendiente es de 0€"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </TabView>
    <Button row="2" *ngIf="!noEntregado" class="btn" text="Confirmar Entrega" (tap)="submit()"></Button>

    <StackLayout row="1" *ngIf="noEntregado">
    <ScrollView class="scrollView">
        <StackLayout class="form-config">
            <Label *ngIf="desc" class="desc" text="{{desc}}"></Label>
            <Button style="width:100%" text="Motivo" (tap)="getMotivos()"></Button>
            <StackLayout class="input-field">
                <TextView hint="Observación." returnKeyType="send" [(ngModel)]="entrega.obsNoEntrega" editable="true" class="input input-border"></TextView>
            </StackLayout>
            <Button class="btn" text="Cancelar Entrega" (tap)="cancel()"></Button>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    </StackLayout>
</GridLayout>
<ActivityIndicator class="activity-indicator" width="100" [busy]="isLoading" height="100"></ActivityIndicator>
```

Comment: You could try to move `<Button class="btn" text="Cancelar Entrega" (tap)="cancel()"></Button>` outside the `ScrollView`. You could move it in the `ScrollView` parent `StackLayout`

Answer (score 0):

This is how i managed my keyboard to not push button up while the textfield get focus.

```
<StackLayout>
<ScrollView >
<CardView shadowColor="#FE00FC" elevation="20" id="container" row="1">
    <GridLayout rows="auto auto auto auto auto auto auto">
        <TextField row="1" hint="User Name" keyboardType="email" autocorrect="false" autocapitalizationType="none" returnKeyType="next" [(ngModel)]="user.name"></TextField>
        <TextField row="2" hint="Password" id="pass" keyboardType="email" secure="true" [(ngModel)]="user.password"></TextField>

        <Button row="3" text="Login" class="submit-button" (tap)="submit()"></Button>
    </GridLayout>
</CardView>
</ScrollView>
</StackLayout>
```